# OS as algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, operating-system

Can an Operating System be considered as an algorithm? Focus on the finiteness property, please. I have contradicting views on it right now with one prof. telling me something and the other something else.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to consider an Operating System, taken as a whole, as an algorithm. I do think it makes sense to look at individual components as algorithms, such as page replacement algorithms, and algorithms used to select the next process to run, or to allocate resources from pools.

Comment: If we go by the definition of algorithm, it says, an algorithm is a finite set of instructions, where each instruction has a clear meaning and executed in a finite amount of time.
On the other hand, if we consider OS as an algorithm, yes it is, just it executes for an infinite amount of time, and can only be completed in finite amount of time, if it is stopped by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on picky little details in your definition of word 'algorithm', which are not relevant in any practical context.

"Yes" is a very good answer, since the OS is an algorithm for computing the next state of the kernel given the previous state and a hardware or software interrupt.  The computer runs this algorithm every time an interrupt occurs.

But if you are being asked to "focus on the finiteness property", then whoever is asking probably wants you to say "no", because the OS doesn't necessarily ever terminate...  (except that when you characterize it as I did above, it does :-)

Answer (score 1):

By definition an Operation System can not be called an algorithm.

Let us take a look at what an algorithm is: 
"a process or set of rules to be followed in calculations or other problem-solving operations, especially by a computer."

The Operating System is composed by set of rules (in the software coding itself) which allow the user to perform tasks on a system but is not defined as a set of rules.

With this said, the Operating System itself is not an algorithm, but we can write an algorithm on how to use it. We can also write algorithms for Operating Systems, defining how it should work, but to call the Operating System itself an algorithm does not make much sense. The Operating System is just a piece of software like any other, though considerably bigger and complex. The question is, would you call MS Word or Photoshop an algorithm?

The Operating System is, however, composed of several algorithms.

I'm sure people will have deferring views on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

From Merriam-Webster: "a procedure for solving a mathematical problem ... in a finite number of steps that frequently involves repetition of an operation".  The problem with an OS, is even if you are talking about a fixed distribution, so that it can consist of a discrete step-by-step procedure, it is not made for solving "a problem".  It is made for solving many problems.  It consists of many algorithms, but it is not a discrete algorithm in and of itself.